# why do I get a truncated .txt file

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate a file containing a short list of random numbers.  Every time I run this code I get a file where the list is truncated, usually in the middle of a number.  I'm using PyCharm.

```
import random

def generate_test(l, r):
    lst = []
    for x in range(1,l):
        lst = lst + [random.randrange(0, r)]
    return lst
test = generate_test(100, 10**12)
test_file = open("test.txt", "wb")
test_file = open("test.txt", "r+")
test_file.write(str(test))
```

Comment: Remove `test_file = open("test.txt", "wb")` and change the next line mode to `a`.

Comment: I'm sure I don't I just copy pasted it from somewhere.  I'm a complete noob.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ so, test_file = open("test.txt", "a")?

Comment: That, and closing the file which the answer mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things I'd like to mention, once you open a file you get that state of the file so if you write, you write in that state, but can't read newly written data. So you do not need to open a file in both(r,w) modes. And last thing I noticed, you didn't close the file.

```
import random

def generate_test(l, r):
    lst = []
    for x in range(1,l):
        lst = lst + [random.randrange(0, r)]
    return lst

test = generate_test(100, 10**12)
print(len(test))   # 99

test_file = open('test.txt', 'w') 
test_file.write(str(test))
test_file.close()
```

Now read the file to verify the written data

```
test_file = open('test.txt','r')
data = test_file.read()
print(len(data.split()))   # 99
test_file.close()
```

Comment: It was the fact that I didn't close it.  The original code (bad though it was) works with the .close.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't create the file correctly, this might be a cleaner code:

```
import random

def generate_test(l, r):
    lst = []
    for x in range(1,l):
        lst = lst + [random.randrange(0, r)]
    return lst

test = generate_test(100, 10**12)

with open("test.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(test))
```